# How to create only one instance of the new window on button click? Caliburn.Macro

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, caliburn.micro

So, I'm learning Caliburn.Micro for MVVM. I figured out how to create a new window inside my "main" ShellView window on a button click, however, I don't understand how to create only one instance of the said window. Right now I can create basically as many as I can by simple clicking on the button that opens new window... I thought about making this button inaccessible when ne window is open, however, I don't know how to check status of the opened window...

My snippet of ShellView.xaml:

```
<Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
    MinWidth="30" MinHeight="30"
    Padding="0" 
    Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"
    x:Name="ShowAnnouncementsView">

    <Border MinHeight="30" MinWidth="30" Background="Bisque"/>
</Button>
```

ShellViewModel.cs:

```
private IWindowManager _windowManager = new WindowManager();    
     
public void ShowAnnouncementsView()
{
    _windowManager.ShowWindow(new AnnouncementsViewModel());
}
```

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: You want the new window to act as a dialog and keep focus, correct? Can you try to replace `_windowManager.ShowWindow(new AnnouncementsViewModel());` with `_windowManager.ShowModalDialog(new AnnoucementsViewModel());`.

Comment: Excellent! This is exactly what I wanted... I guess I should have looked at other functions of WindowManager before submitting the question.. thank you mate!

Comment: No worries, I didn’t find a ton of documentation for Caliburn Micro, so I’m glad that worked. Standard WPF uses `Window.ShowDialog()` or I wouldn’t have had anything to go on.

Comment: Well. Actually there was no showmodaldialog function so I simply used the standard one which is showdialog and it worked.. my problem was that I assumed that showdialog is like for a pop-up notification... I should have tried different ones before shit posting